# Translating macro from Common Lisp to Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros, common-lisp

I'm trying to translate the Common Lisp code in [the original "Calendrical Calculations" paper by Derhowitz and Reingold](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachum/papers/cc-paper.pdf) to Clojure. In this paper there is a macro named `sum` which is given in Common Lisp as

```
(defmacro sum (expression index initial condition)
;; sum expession for index = initial and successive integers,
;; as long as condition holds.
 (let* ((temp (gensym)))
   `(do ((,temp 0 (+ ,temp ,expression))
         (,index ,initial (i+ ,index))) 
        ((not ,condition) ,temp))))
```

and which I've translated to Clojure as

```
(defmacro sum [expression index initial condition]
  ; sum expession for index = initial and successive integers,
  ; as long as condition holds.
  (let [temp (gensym)]
    `(do ((~temp 0 (+ ~temp ~expression))
          (~index ~initial (inc ~index))) 
         ((not ~condition) ~temp))))
```

However, when I use the above in a function (for example, the following)

```
(defn absolute-from-gregorian [date]
  ;; Absolute date equivalent to the Gregorian date.
  (let [month (extract-month date) 
        year  (extract-year date)]
    ; Return
    (+ (extract-day date)           ;; Days so far this month.
       (sum                         ;; Days in prior months this year.
         (last-day-of-gregorian-month m year) m 1 (< m month))
       (* 365 (dec year))           ;; Days in prior years.
       (quotient (dec year) 4)      ;; Julian leap days in prior years...
       (-                           ;; ... minus prior century years...
         (quotient (dec year) 100))
       (quotient                    ;; ...plus prior years divisible...
         (dec year) 400))))         ;; ... by 400.
```

I get an error similar to the following:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve
  symbol: G__53 in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:165:8)
```

I'm almost completely unfamiliar with the Lisp/Clojure macro system, but from what I can determine it's saying that the `gensym` invocation in the `let` block has created a symbol (in this case `G__53`) which is being invoked, but which doesn't exist. *That* makes sense, but I suspect it's not the intent of the original code - however, I don't know much about Common Lisp and thus I'm not able to figure out A) what the original CL code is trying to do here, and B) how to produce a Clojure equivalent to this.

For what it's worth - the Clojure version of the other functions used in `absolute-from-gregorian` are:

```
(defn quotient [m n]
  (int (Math/floor (/ m n))))

(defn extract-month [date]
  (first date))

(defn extract-day [date]
  (second date))

(defn extract-year [date]
  (second (rest date)))
```

Any and all pointers as to how to make this work greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be expressed with a `loop` construct in Clojure:

```
(defmacro sum [expression index initial condition]
  ; sum expession for index = initial and successive integers,
  ; as long as condition holds.
  `(loop [~index ~initial temp# 0]
     (if ~condition 
       (recur (inc ~index) (+ temp# ~expression))
       temp#)))
```

Example:

```
(sum (* x x) x 1 (<= x 3)) ;; => 14
```

Note also that it may be sufficient to use Clojure's standard constructs instead of custom macros. As an example, the line in the code with the calendar calculations can be rewritten as:

```
(reduce + (map #(last-day-of-gregorian-month % year) (range 1 month)))
```

Comment: Many thanks. After posting my question I'd continued to work on this and had determined that a loop with `recur` would be appropriate, but not knowing much about Clojure/Lisp macros I hadn't reached the point of figuring out how to put it together. Looks like I'll have to pick up [the book on Clojure macros](https://pragprog.com/book/cjclojure/mastering-clojure-macros) and spend some time learning more about them.

Answer (score 4):

`do` in common lisp doesn't act anything like `do` in clojure. You'll have to look up what `do` actually does (it's a looping construct in common lisp, and a grouping construct in clojure), and figure out how to accomplish the same thing.